# What To Make Of Encoded URLs in Log Files

Tags: security, web

I have been getting URL requests in my Web server log files for sometime, but I don't quite understand what they are. For instance:

```
GET /sample-url-1-%83%C6%92%C3%86%E2%80%99%C3%83%E2%80%92%C3%82%C2%A2%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC%C3%85%C2%A1%C3%83%E2%80%9A%C3%82%C2%AC%C3%83%C6%92%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5 HTTP/1.1
GET /sample-url-2-%83%C6%92%C3%82%C2%A2%82%AC%AC%C3%83%E2%80%9A%C3%82%C2%A6  HTTP/1.1
```

The 2 above are just examples. There are many variants.

When I try to decode the funny characters with Python, I only get funny characters which are possibly non-English language chars.

Are these requests harmful? If they are, how to guard against them?

Comment: Do they actually say "sample url"? Are these real, actual urls from your logs or are these obfuscated?

Comment: The sample URLs are not obfuscated. I merely replaced the clear text. The funny characters (encoded part of the URL) are real.